# How to reduce the size of Next.js local cache directory?

Tags: caching, next.js

Next.js uses a local cache directory to optimise the performance of the local development server. I have a project where this directory uses 2.7 GB of disk space, which I consider quite high, given my disk space constraints.

I looked through the documentation to figure out if there's a way to limit how much space it uses, but couldn't find anything. There is an article on [setting up caching in CI envirnoments](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/ci-build-caching) and a file with [description of every config allowed by next.config.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/server/config-shared.ts#L158), but nothing in there regarding the local cache directory and limiting its size.

I mostly run the local app using a dev server with `next dev` command. I rarely use a local build with `next build` and I'm comfortable with manually clearing some cache after using `next build`, if needed.

**Is it possible to limit the size of the cache directory?** How can I do that?

Here's the disk space usage of my `.next` directory given by `dust`:
[image: .next directory size by dust]

---

I don't really know how the caching works. Does it include all the compiled code, including packages from `node_modules`? Is this a problem with my application being so large? Perhaps I should be looking to reduce that instead?

I use yarn v3 for package management, without plug-n-play. **Is there something in my package manager setup that I can do to help reduce disk space usage of the next cache directory?**

Here's the disk space usage of the `node_modules` directory:
[image]